# Why 1.-5 = -4.0

Tags: java

```
public static void main(String[] args){
        System.out.println(1.-5); // -4.0

}
```

Can anyone explain why i got the above result, thanks in advance.

Comment: Why wouldn't you get that result?

Answer (score 9, accepted):

It's because it's equivalent to `1.0-5.0`

Answer (score 4):

That's due to implicit type conversion (http://en.wikipedia.org/wiki/Type_conversion) where 5 is promoted to 5.0 due to presence of 1. (which is equivalent to 1.0, a double).

Answer (score 3):

`System.out.println(1.-5);` is equivalent to `System.out.println(1.0-5.0);`

So the result is `-4.0`

Answer (score 1):

Subtracting 5 from 1 gives the result -4.

Answer (score 0):

> Your System.out.println() takes the calculation as 1.00 - 5.0 (a dot
>   tells the type of the arguments  as "double"). So the result is -4.0
>   and hence it prints the same.